# How to check webkit element styles in chrome devtools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have `<input type="file"` on my page. I want ti view file's button styles in chrome dev tools. Unfortunately if I this element it show styles for element whole input ( I mean text + button). I want to inspect styles for `::-webkit-file-upload-button`. For example firefox shows all styles when a select the element. Is there any way I can do this in chrome?

The images below represents an example. It's clear a button in the image was styled using `::-webkit-file-upload-button`, but there're no `background-color`/`bacgrkound-image` in styles list.  How do I view styles for webkit-element?
[image]

Comment: Try enabling "shadow DOM" in devtools settings.

Comment: That's it, if you post your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @wOxxOm answered I should enable `Shadow DOM` in devtool settings.[image]